# Помогите получить переменную из ajax в php

Tags: javascript, php

Имеется такой кусок кода ajax:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "index.php",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: { option: option.number },
    success:function(data) 
    {
        alert(data);            
    }
})
```

Переменная 'option.number' каждый раз генерирует новое число. В 'alert' это число успешно отображается, а вот в php никак.

Пробовал выводить так:

```
if(isset($_POST['option']))
{
    $option = $_POST['option'];
    echo 'Число: '.$option.'';
    exit();
}
```

выдаёт пустую страницу. Пожалуйста помогите, уже 3 день головую ломаю как сделать вывод переменной из ajax в php. Заранее спасибо большое!

Comment: если в alert есть значит сервер всё возвращает. так что не ясно что ты имеешь в виду под "а вот в php никак" и "выдаёт пустую страницу"

Comment: Отображается пустая страница в php, нет этого самого вывода из ajax.

Comment: как может отображаться белая страница **В PHP** если ты запрос делаешь аяксом **на JS**?

Comment: " нет этого самого вывода из ajax" --- ты же пишешь "В 'alert' это число успешно отображается"

Comment: В alert отображается, а на странице index.php пусто.

Comment: Так когда Вы отправляете ajax запрос и получаете ответ от сервера, оно не будет нигде отображаться до тех пор, пока при помощи JS Вы его не обработаете и никуда не выведите.

Comment: Так  а зачем ты открываешь `index.php` напрямую? ты же запрашиваешь данные из клиента у неё.....ты на клиенте обратился к скрипту, скрипт отработал и умер. Дальше на клиенте делаешь с полученными данными что нужно

Comment: ну если в alert отображается всё, то вместо alert надо использовать манипулирование DOM.... метод например querySelector и свойство  text/innerHTML

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста как правильно нужно обработать код в js и вывести его в качестве переменной PHP на странице, я новичок в js ajax..

Comment: вместо alert написать что-то вида `$("#xxx").text(data)` предварительно добавив в код страницы элемент `<div id="xxx" style="color:red; font-size:5rem"></div>`

Comment: Наконец то удалось теперь получить ответ от ajax на странице при помощи переменной <div id="xxx"></div>. Число отображается на странице, но насколько я понял эта строка является не числом. Подскажите как сделать из этой строки число, чтобы можно было его использовать примерно вот таким образом: $option = '<div id="xxx"></div>'; if($option == 1) { echo ''Выпало число: 1; } if($option == 2) { echo 'Выпало число: 2'; } и т.д

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы открываете страницу в браузере, к ней идёт запрос методом GET, а не POST.
Чтобы index.php верно отрабатывал GET и POST запросы, в нём нужно вместо переменной $_POST использовать переменную $_REQUEST.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['option']))
{
    $option = $_REQUEST['option'];
    echo 'Число: '.$option.'';
    exit();
}
```